# Simple arithmetic in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, number-line

For example if I plot number line and add $0 + 12$, then subtract $12 -12$ (if I wrote this in one line it would be: $(0+12)-12$), how it would be implemented in set theory? $A = \{x \in R\ |\ x \in [0,12]\}$ $([0] \cup A]) \setminus A = \emptyset$? Or mathematical operations can't touch first element ($(0,12]$)?

Comment: What do you mean with symbols $[0]$ and $[0,12]$ ? The sets containing $0$ and $0$ and $12$ respectively ?

Comment: In set theory [numbers are "implemented" as sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers), but the number $12$ is not the set $\{ 12 \}$. There are more than one way to implement numbers as sets; according to [another one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Zermelo_ordinals): $12 = \{ 11 \}$.

Comment: Regarding your proposal, consider this simple example. According to [Set union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) we have that: $\{ a \} \cup \{ a \} = \{ a \}$. Thus: $\{ 12 \} \cup \{ 12 \} = \{ 12 \}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I have to edit the question. Every number on number line is a range of numbers in set theory (ex.: $1 =  \{x \in R\ |\ x \in [0;1]\}$). My question is: if i sum x and y, should I think about y, something like $[0;y]$ or $(0;y]$?

Comment: Maybe you have to avoid speaking of sets and consider *segments*: the number $n$ will be implemented on the number line with segment $[0,n]$ (that is the same as the interval.

Comment: Because, if I add to 0 two ($[0] \cup \{x \in R\ |\ x \in [0;12]\}$) and then subtract two ($([0] \cup \{x \in R\ |\ x \in [0;12]\}) \setminus {x \in R\ |\ x \in [0;12]}$) I'll receive $\emptyset$, not a zero

Comment: But if $x=[0,x]$ and $y=[0,y]$ you cannot simply take the union, because if $x \le y$ you will have $x+y=[0,x] \cup [0,y]=[0,y]$. You have to "translate" the segment $[0,y]$ in such a way that the "old" $0$ coincide with $x$ to get $[0,x+y]$.

Comment: Nothing changes... $(0,y] \setminus (0,y]= \emptyset$ and not $[0]$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, A line segment is a non-empty set, so when I add something I need to take range(0,10] or range[0,10]? Because If I try $([0] \cup range(0,10]) \setminus range(0,10]$ it will return 0. So when I count, should I include first num or not? If no, then why we are counting a segments from 0, but not from next minimal num?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$

$0=|\emptyset|,12=|A|$, where the $|X|$ symbol means cardinality of the set $X$

$(0+12)-12$ means, in set operations, $$(A\cup\emptyset) \setminus A$$
which obviously gives $\emptyset$.